# Seeing if a text file contains a word in php

Tags: php, text-files

I want to look at a string and see if any of the words in the string match the words in a text file.

lets say i have a product.txt file and it contains:

apple
sony
dyson
mcdonalds
ipod

here is my code:

```
    <?php

$productFile = file_get_contents('products.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

/*
* product.txt file contains
* apple
* pc
* ipod
* mcdonalds
*/

$status = 'i love watching tv on my brand new apple mac';

    if (strpos($status,$productFile) !== false) {
        echo 'the status contains a product';
    }

    else{
        echo 'The status doesnt contain a product';
    }

?>
```

right now its telling me the status doesnt contain a product which it does, can anyone see where im going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're searching for the word list as a whole in the string. Instead, you have to search for every word in the word list separately. For example, [`str_word_count`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) can be used to split the string into words.

```
<?php

$productFile = file_get_contents('products.txt');
$products = str_word_count($productFile, 1);

$status = 'i love watching tv on my brand new apple mac';

$found = false;
foreach ($products as $product)
{
    if (strpos($status,$product) !== false) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($found) {
    echo 'the status contains a product';
}
else {
    echo 'The status doesnt contain a product';
}

?>
```

You may also want to consider `stripos` instead of `strpos` for case-insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$productFile = file_get_contents('products.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

/*
* product.txt file contains
* apple
* pc
* ipod
* mcdonalds
*/

$status = 'i love watching tv on my brand new apple mac';
$status = str_replace(' ', '|', $status);

if ( preg_match('/'.$status.'/m',$productFile) ) {
    echo 'the status contains a product';
}
else {
    echo 'The status doesnt contain a product';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you mixed up the variable order ([Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php))

```
mixed strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

And then you have to check each word manually, the whole string does not exist in the file, just one word does. Create an array using `explode()` for instance and use a `foreach` loop.